# opening git diff in sublime using python for custom command

Tags: python, git, sublimetext2

The core.editor of my git is sublime, but I am launching sublime in my custom git command made in python, so how can i pass `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` to sublime as argument in python

I have stored the value of core.editor in configdb['core.editor'] which i can launch using `subprocess.Popen` but passing `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` as argument opens 4 tabs with title git, diff, HEAD^, HEAD... how should I make any sublime launched with git diff into which i can add my own message that I can store in a variable using python.

```
# Read git config file
configFile, _ = execGitCommand('git config --list')
configDb = {}
for line in filter(None, configFile.split("\n")):
    configDb[line.split("=")[0]] = line.split("=")[-1]
```

now `configDb['core.editor'] = /Applications/Sublime_Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n -w`

and then

```
diff = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', 'HEAD^', 'HEAD'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
msg, err, = subprocess.Popen(configDb['core.editor'].split(" ")[0], stdin=diff.stdout)
```

but executing the last line above does opens the diff in sublime but gives below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/san/Development/executables//git-ipush", line 186, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/san/Development/executables//git-ipush", line 43, in main
    preCheck(args)
  File "/Users/san/Development/executables//git-ipush", line 55, in preCheck
    msg, err, = subprocess.Popen(configDb['core.editor'].split(" ")[0], stdin=diff.stdout)
TypeError: 'Popen' object is not utterable
```

and terminal is now not waiting for sublime to finish editing,  but it should as I am passing `-w` flag as you can see above. The code is a part of [this git-command](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40084/git-command-push-the-latest-commit-and-email-the-diff-in-colour)

Comment: Have you tried `git diff | subl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me in the Python console of Sublime Text 3 (after I had already set my current working directory to my git working copy):

```
    >>> import subprocess
    >>> diff = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', 'HEAD^', 'HEAD'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    >>> subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/subl'], stdin=diff.stdout)
```

**edit:**
OK, I *think* I understand what you want now.  You want to edit the text of the diff before you send it into Sublime, right?  The following worked for me:

```
import subprocess, tempfile
diff = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'diff', 'HEAD^', 'HEAD'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write('Hello, World\n')
    f.write(diff.stdout.read())
    f.seek(0)
    subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/subl'], stdin=f)
```

This is just a sample.  If you actually want to modify the contents of the diff itself, you can read it into a string first.  Note that you can't use `StringIO` (which I think would be better), because somewhere in the second `Popen` somebody needs a `fileno`.

**edit 2:**
Here's how you get the text from Sublime into a variable

```
import sublime

window = sublime.active_window()
view = window.active_view()
region = sublime.Region(0, view.size())
text = view.substr(region)
```

Comment: this works, but when I launched the sublime with diff, I added few more lines in the starting, now I wanted to save and return the data to variable through `subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/subl'], stdin=diff.stdout)` but that doesn't seem to work, I also tried sublime with following flags ` -n -w` but then subprocess errors out saying `  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exceptionOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` any idea how to get value return to a variable so it can be used further

Comment: Post your code (edit your original question to show it) so I can see what you're doing.  That may help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: :I have added piece of code I am using to open the diff in sublime.. thanks.

Comment: no man I am trying to update the text i.e. added to diff that opens in sublime and then store in a variable to send. but in the edit, you have edited the diff before it reaches sublime, I want to edit in sublime and then pass on the edited text to a variable. I hope you understand now .

Comment: feel free to accept my answer if it was useful to you :-)

Comment: up vote my question, I'll accept your answer when I get back home, from mobile doesn't work...